# Converting from UITextField to Int failure

Tags: string, swift2, uitextfield

I cannot convert the `UITextField` to an `Int`, although I have taken a look at the instructions on the internet. I'm a beginner with Swift 2. Can anyone help?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var age: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var resultLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func findAge(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        // Changed "enteredAge = age" to "enteredAge = age!"
        var age = Int = Int(age.text)
        var enteredAge = Int(age)

        if enteredAge != nil {

            var catYears = enteredAge! * 7

            resultLabel.text = "Your cat is \(catYears) in cat years"

        } else {

            resultLabel.text = "Please enter a number in the box"

        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Entered age use age.text again as in age variable

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your code you are redeclaring the age textfield , I am editing you IBAction . I have not run this code , but I think It will work for you . Just copy paste in your code any check it .

```
@IBAction func findAge(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        var ageToInt =  Int(self.age.text!)!

        if ageToInt != nil {

            var catYears = ageToInt! * 7

            resultLabel.text = "Your cat is \(catYears) in cat years"

        } else {

            resultLabel.text = "Please enter a number in the box"

        }
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: Xcode said that ageToInt is non-optional type Int and we cannot force unwrap it and comparing non-optional value of type Int to nil always turn true

Comment: Remove un raping and try like this   Int(self.age.text!)